# Frequency or Angular Frequency

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, solid-state-physics

I am doing study on electromagnetism and Drude model is applied recently in my simulation. I am quite confused about the exact meaning of the terms in the expression of the dielectric constant in Drude model.

I have tried with the case of gold and here is what I got from my calculations:

One the one hand, the $\omega$ within in the denominator should be interpreted as the angular frequency with rad/s as the unit. On the other hand, the plasma frequency in the numerate and the damping coefficient in the denominator should be interpreted as the frequency with unit Hz.

By interpreted I mean just substitute in the value of the quantity while it is with that particular unit

But can the angular frequency just be added with frequency given their different units?

Comment: Both frequency and angular frequency are measure in Hz.   You have to be told if the variables are angular or not, although there is a very very strong convention that $\omega$ is angular frequency, and a somewhat strong convention that $f$ is frequency.  Often it doesn't matter, as the expression is the ratio of frequencies. (Assuming the author didn't do something stupid.) But you can't add variables if one is $f$ and the other $\omega$.

Comment: @garyp It is killing me. I have substitute the value of $\omega$ when it is in rad/s and the values of $\omega_p$ and $\Gamma$ when they are in 1/s to get the right dielectric constant of for example gold, which is well established.

Comment: @garyp the expressions are in this link,https://www.horiba.com/fileadmin/uploads/Scientific/Downloads/OpticalSchool_CN/TN/ellipsometer/Drude_Dispersion_Model.pdf

Comment: Please can you write out the calculation you are doing using mathjax and include all the numerical values and the units.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add them if they have different units, you are correct.

They are related simply by a factor of $2\pi$,

$$ \omega = 2\pi\nu$$

where $\nu$ is in Hz and $\omega$ is rads/s.